# POD low dimensional vector in boost

Tags: c++, boost, vector, math

I'm looking for POD low dimension vectors (2,3 and 4D let say) with all the necessary arithmetic niceties (operator +, - and so on). POD low dimension matrices would be great as well.

boost::ublas vectors are not POD, there's a pointer indirection somewhere (vector are resizeable).

Can I find that anywhere in boost? Using boost::array along with boost.operator lib is an options but maybe I'm missing something easier elsewhere?

Apart boost, does anybody know any good library around?

PS: POD <=> plain old data

**EDIT:**

Otherwise, here are some other links I gathered from another thread:

- http://www.cgal.org/
- http://geometrylibrary.geodan.nl
- http://www.cmldev.net
- http://www.openexr.com/index.html
- http://project-mathlibs.web.cern.ch/project-mathlibs/sw/html/SMatrix.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a nice Vector library for 3d graphics in the prophecy SDK:

Check out http://www.twilight3d.com/downloads.html

Comment: Is it easy to extract from the rest of the SDK?

Comment: If I remember correctly it's a header only library that only depends on a few standard c++ headers so it should be trivial to extract.

Comment: it is trivial indeed. light-weight, full-featured. I might go for it.

Comment: Glad you liked it. Checked it out again and I must say I think it's an amazing piece of C++.

Answer (score 3):

The [blitz++](http://www.oonumerics.org/blitz/examples/Blitz++/transform.html) TinyMatrix / TinyVector is what you want I think,

you also have the [libeigen](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org).

Comment: yes indeed, nice code, dimensions are "templated". Still, it's a bit dry with 3D specific features like getting euler angles, inverting a matrix...

Comment: Definitely, eigen rocks them all :P

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at STL's ***valarray*** container?

Checkout this answer to a related SO question:
[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/152745/optimising-c-2-d-arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/152745/optimising-c-2-d-arrays/152761#152761)